# Is a Hong Kong permit required by a Chinese citizen from foreign country - transit in PEK - Hong Kong?

Tags: china

For a Chinese citizen, a Chinese passport is normally not valid for entering Hong Kong or Macau. A two-way permit with a valid Hong Kong endorsement is used to visit Hong Kong. However, Hong Kong allows Chinese citizens to enter Hong Kong using a Chinese passport for the purpose of transit from a foreign country within 7 days without any endorsement, i.e. you can enter Hong Kong after returning from the U.S. using your Chinese passport only, by stating that you are returning to the mainland.

However, a lot of travellers had trouble on the return journey by using routing like HKG - PEK - foreign country on cheap CA tickets.

On the outbound trip, when entering Hong Kong, the travellers show the air ticket and a valid visa to the foreign country, and takes the flight to the foreign country without any trouble, transiting in PEK. However, on the return trip, they are blocked from boarding without a valid Hong Kong endorsement in their two-way permit.

Does anyone know / have experience on a such trip, i.e. from foreign country, transiting at PEK airside, fly to Hong Kong or Macau, and return to mainland China by land or sea? Can you complete the trip with your Chinese passport only?

Answer (score 2):

The route you are thinking of isn't a transit in HKG/MO. It's a round-trip Mainland<>HKG/MO. That's a no-no for your purpose, as you will have to show an onward ticket to overseas (coming from PEK).

Note that in PEK, you might or might not transit airside -- if you have to transit between T1/T2 and T3, you will have to enter China, and exit it again.

However, if you have a residence permit from overseas, you can get two weeks, I think. Friend's fiancée used to do that.

Alternatively, you could return to the Mainland via Taipei. Book HKG-TPE, and TPE-somewhere in the Mainland, under two separate tickets. But you'd need the travel permit for Taipei, too.